# Mouseover and Mouseleave Jquery image swap. Works on local side - not on server?

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseleave

I'm trying to make a mouseover/mouseleave image swap seen below. It's working great on my local side but once on my server the mouseleave gives me a broken link icon where the image should be. Looking at it with developers tools the code is working great, except for the broken link. I know the image path is working because the image is there when loaded and before hover.

I'm pretty stumped and any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="testing123"><img src="images/BotGrid/images/blackFull_05_03.png"  /></div>





$(document).ready(function(){

$('.testing123').on('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','images/BotGrid/images/yellowfull_05_03.png');
    $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "black"});
});

$('.testing123').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr('src','images/BotGrid/images/blackfull_05_03.png');
    $(this).css({"backgroundColor": "yellow"});
});

});
```

Comment: So the yellowfull image is displayed correctly?  And the blackfull image is displayed before you mouseover?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at some other sources online and this link ([Jquery Mouseenter/Mouse Leave image swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396715/jquery-mouseenter-mouse-leave-image-swap)) I found that I need to call the .hover function instead of individually calling mouseover and mouseleave. Here's a solution that worked for me:

```
<div class="bottomsquares">
<img src="images/BotGrid/images/blackFull_05_03.png"  class="static" name="aeffect" alt="" />        
<img src="images/BotGrid/images/yellowfull_05_03.png"  class="rollover" name="aeffect" alt="" />

 </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".rollover").hide();
$(".bottomsquares").hover(
function(){
    $(this).find(".static,.rollover").toggle();
}, 
function(){
    $(this).find(".static,.rollover").toggle();
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(".bottomsquares").hover(function() {

$(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
}, function() {
$(this).css('background-color', '#f9e42b');
});
</script>
```